# Specify version of package installed from name @ git url with pip

Tags: python, pip

When installing a github package via `pip` from `setup.py` with the format

```
{name} @ git+https://{oauth}@github.com/{repo}/{package}@{release_tag}#egg={name}-{version}
```

- How do you get pip to pick up the `version` you are trying to pass?

Installing this way, pip can parse out the package name and URL but not the version. This means that it thinks the requirement is already satisfied by an older version already installed.

Installing via a URL in the command line works ok and it can parse out the required version

I also tried `{name}=={version}@{url}` but this way pip doesn't look in git and only in `pypi`

Comment: The correct syntax is `#egg={name}-{version}` — i.e., minus, not `==`. The correct syntax for the command line is `pip install git+https://{oauth}@github.com/{repo}/{package}.git@{release_tag}#egg={name}-{version}`. Syntax `name @ git+https://URL` is for `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question, I had only been trying via `setup.py` and the problem still persists, I can install via the command line the individual package ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently allowed in `pip`, explanation linked in this pip issue

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8197